# Extracting a list of strings from a text file

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to extract a vector that contains all strings in a txt file using c++, which I have almost no experience. In java or matlab, this would have been really easy, all I have to do is

1. Read a long list of character sequence from the txt file.
2. Loop through this sequence and extract the strings.

In c++ there seems to be a lot more things that I have to deal with, for example, I am asked to

1. Add a new C++ header (.h) file to my program and in it please declare an enumeration for the different array indices that are relevant.
2. Declare a file parsing function that takes two parameters: a reference to a Standard Template library (STL) vector of C++ style strings (e.g., of type vector &), and a C-style string (of type char *);

Non of these makes too much sense to me. Is there a good source to get help on this?

Comment: Yah, C++ is meant to give you more control under the hood, and C even more then C++, and then of course Assembly more than C. You will need to figure out what you want as a delimiter between each string, and then figure out if you want to read in via binary, or text.  If you are going to be messing with C++ a good amount in the future, I suggest getting the book, "C++, An Active Learning Approach", from Randal Albert and Todd Breedlove. This a fantastic book that you can go through without needing to be taught C++ in a classroom setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read the file:

```
std::ifstream in("foo.txt");
std::stringstream buffer;
buffer << in.rdbuf();
```

After that there are various ways to split up the contents, depending on your exact requirements.

Comment: thanks. Where should this foo.txt be stored so that it can be read by my program. (I am running it from the command line and the projected is created using visual basic). Should be it stored in the same place as the project directory?

Comment: You can either make sure the file is in the current working directory or you can use a full path for the file name, e.g. `std::ifstream in("/path/tofoo.txt");`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new to C++, I recommend you check out this website: http://www.cplusplus.com/

Parsing from input files is relatively easy if you are using command line to run your program. Simply include the main function as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

Then, access the parameters passed in using argv as an array:

```
var = argv[0];
```

Declare a char array and then use that array to capture each line of the file.

```
char input[MAX_SIZE];
while(cin.getline(input, MAX_SIZE))
{
    //Each time this executes, input contains all characters of a line, like a string
    //e.g. make it a String and add it to a vector of type String
    //do something with input[]
}
```

Your file parsing function can receive the two parameters that I specified in the main parameters, but these must also be declared as parameters to main.  Then, your function can grab the input the way I demonstrated.

As for your header file, I'm not exactly sure what kinds of enumerations you mean, but you can find syntax and rules for enumeration on the site given above. If I recall correctly, enumerations are similar in Java and C++.